# VS 2019: Error occurred trying to load Windows Form: Value cannot be null Parameter propertyName

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5, windows-forms-designer, windows-forms-core

My team are currently unable to load any of the Windows forms in our Visual Studio project due to this error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'propertyName')

This error occurs when we double click on the [Dialog]Dlg.cs file associated with any of our Windows forms.

Edit:After installing VS 2022, the same issue occurs but now at least we are given a stacktrace:  StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'propertyName')
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__143`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHost.d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
RPC server exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'propertyName')
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ResXGlobalObject.ResourceGlobalObject..ctor(ResXGlobalObject globalObject, ResXDataNode node, Type resourceType, String resourceName, String propertyName, String combinedName)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ResXGlobalObject.BuildType()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ResXGlobalObject.GetObjectType()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.GlobalObject.get_ObjectType()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ResXGlobalObject.get_Children()
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ProjectResXGlobalObjectProvider.AddResourcesToGlobalCollection(String identifier, GlobalResourceFileData globalResource)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.ProjectResXGlobalObjectProvider.UpdateGlobalObjectCollectionStoreForSource(String identifier)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.GlobalObjectProvider.InitializeOrUpdateProjectResources(GlobalResourceFileData[] resources)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.GlobalObjects.GlobalObjectService.InitializeOrUpdateGlobalResources(GlobalResourceFileData[] globalResources)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.DesignToolsServer.InitializeAsync(ServerInitializationOptions options)

Pop up :

[image]

We are using VS 2019 and targeting .NET 5.0
We've also updated VS. Currently on VS Professional 2019 v16.11.10 (4.8.04084).

I've searched everywhere but can't find any examples of this particular issue. Have tried almost everything, including some advice on similar issues with "Value cannot be null" such as editing the AssemblyInfo.cs and changing ComVisible, etc.

We have checked the VS ActivityLog.xml but this error doesn't show up in the log and we've tried to find ways to debug it but so far none of those methods have worked for us. It's hard for us to fix the "propertyName" is VS doesn't provide us with some ideas on what that is.

Any tips appreciated as our only other option at the moment seems to be to

Update 2, 9th March 2022:
16.8.0 -> Clicking on our cs file loads the Winform correctly.
16.9.4 (and newer) -> It is broken

On 16.8 it looks as follows:

[image]

Update 3, 14th March 2022
See stacktrace - thanks to MS we found a way to get a more detailed trace as you now see above.

Comment: Start small: Does it work for a new Winforms project? What has changed since it worked?

Comment: Does this happen when opening in the code editor or only when opening the forms designer? If the latter, looking at the .designer.cs file associated with the form / control (or any base class if you're deriving from your own base class) may shed some light on what's wrong.

Comment: I would suggest using the "Report a Problem" feature of VS to open a ticket with Microsoft so someone on the VS team can take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: Since `PropertyName` is part of data binding, my bet would be, that your data source (e.g. `DataSet`) is somehow messed up. This could be some configuration change, failure to instantiate a data source at runtime, changed permissions or alike (e.g. if you have a database behind it)... it is hard to tell without us knowing, what exaclty your application does - data binding wise.

Comment: @PMF Yes it works for a new Winforms project, but not a new form within the current project. This is a massive project with a lot of dependencies so quite a lot has changed.

Comment: @sbridewell It happens only when opening the forms designer. We don't see a smoking gun in the designer.cs but will continue looking

Comment: Added the new VS 2022 stack trace to my main post now, thanks for comments

Comment: Do you have any static initializer code in your forms? These may cause issues. And do the forms work when the code is run?

Comment: @PMF We have a static constructor and plenty of static methods and variables, yes. This prevents us from instantiating too many instances of controls.

Comment: Please see my main post again. On version 16.8.0 clicking on our cs file loads the Winform correctly! 16.9.4 (and newer) -> It is broken

Comment: @C.Callanan I've had a similar problem with a recent update (don't know exactly which version it was). Removing the static constructor helped. Static instances of controls should be avoided, as they're prone to cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is a bug, and it is now being worked on:
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6849

Please see the above git thread to see the current workaround for those who need to get it going asap.